# Django NoReverseMatch Error while Deploying

Tags: django, deployment, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django-friendship package for follower relationship . In localhost it works great but when i deploy it gives an error as

```
Reverse for 'follower_add_new' with arguments '('Bora.gulerrr',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['tr/friendship/follower/add/(?P<followee_username>\\w+)/$']
```

I don't know why it is giving error while deploying.

views.py

```
@login_required
    def follower_add(request, followee_username, template_name='friendship/follow/add.html'):



        """ views.py """
        #ctx = {'followee_username': followee_username}

        if request.method == 'POST':
            followee = user_model.objects.get(username=followee_username)
            follower = request.user
            try:
                Follow.objects.add_follower(follower, followee)
            except AlreadyExistsError as e:
                ctx['errors'] = ["%s" % e]
            else:
                return redirect('followees')

        return render(request, template_name, ctx)
    `
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
       re_path(r'^follower/add/(?P<followee_username>\w+)/$',follower_add,name = "follower_add_new"),
       re_path(r'^follower/remove/(?P<followee_username>\w+)/$',follower_remove,name = "follower_remove_new"),

    ]
```

home.html

```
<div class="col">
        <h4>{%trans "People and Companies" %}</h4><br><br>
        <h5>{%trans "Filter" %}</h5>
        <form method="get">
            {{ filter.form| crispy }}
            <button type="submit">{%trans "Search" %}</button><br><br>
        </form>

        {% for user in filter.qs %}
            {% if not user in blocking %}
                {% if not user in blockers %}        

                    {% if not user in followees  %} 

                            <table class="table">
                                <tbody id="myTable">                            
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'user:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">
                                        {% if user.accounts.image %}
                                        <img src="{{user.accounts.image.url}}" width="50" alt="Profile Photo">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        {% else %} No Photo &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {% endif %}
                                        {% if user.first_name %}
                                        {{ user.first_name }}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ user.last_name }}{% else %}{{ user.username }}{% endif %}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{% if not user in followees %}
                                        <a href="{% url 'follower_add_new' user.username %}">follow</a>{% else %}
                                        <a href="{% url 'follower_remove_new' user.username %}">unfollow</a>{% endif %}
                                        | <a href="{% url 'block_add' user.username %}">block</a> </th>                     
                                </tr>                           
                                </tbody> 

                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}

            {% else %}

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>


    </div>
```

Comment: What is this `Bora.gulerrr'` is this follower

Comment: "Bora.gulerrr " is username of someone who is just signed up

Comment: So when you are going to this link `follower/add/Bora.gulerrr ` is it giving error

Comment: I list the people who sign up on my website and you can add the user on your followers list like instagram.

Comment: Can you share `followees` url please

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\w+` for username. This allows uppercase A-Z, lowercase a-z, digits 0-9 and underscore. However it does not allow `.`, so the URL for `Bora.gulerrr` will not match.

You can fix the problem by limiting usernames to match `\w+`, creating a slug field for the user model that matches `\w+`, or by accepting more characters, for example:

```
re_path(r'^follower/add/(?P<followee_username>[\w\.-]+)/$',follower_add,name = "follower_add_new"),
re_path(r'^follower/remove/(?P<followee_username>[\w\.-]+)/$',follower_remove,name = "follower_remove_new"),
```